# NullPointedException when using Spring RestTemplate in Java

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, get, resttemplate

I'm using the latest Springframework, and having issues trying to GET an int from my server. All code was writen in Java.

When I interact with the server throught browser everything is OK. And when interacting with the server through the client I'm getting a `NullPointerException`.

Keep in mind I am a beginner software student.

**Server Code** (I tried both, works fine when using browser):

```
public class RestController {

    private GameSession gameSession = new GameSession();

    @RequestMapping(value = "registerPlayer")
    public int registerPlayer(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("mode") boolean mode) {
        return gameSession.registerPlayer(name, mode);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "registerPlayer/{name}/{mode}")
    public int registerPlayer(@PathVariable String name, @PathVariable boolean mode) {
        return gameSession.registerPlayer(name, mode);
    }

}
```

**Client Code** (again tried both, with the same result):

```
@Component
public class GameSessionClient implements ISeaBattleGame{

    @Autowired
    private RestOperations restOperations;
    private String url;

    @Override
    public int registerPlayer(String name, boolean singlePlayerMode) {
        url = "http://localhost:8080/" + "registerPlayer?name=" + name + "&mode=" + (singlePlayerMode ? 1 : 0);
        return restOperations.getForObject(url, int.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int registerPlayer(String name, boolean singlePlayerMode) {
        url = "http://localhost:8080/" + "registerPlayer/" + name + "/" + (singlePlayerMode ? 1 : 0);
        return restOperations.getForObject(url, int.class);
    }
}
```

**RestConfig Code**:

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestOperations createRestTemplate(final ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory){
        return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory(@Value("${connect.timeout}") final int connectTimeout, @Value("${read.timeout}") final int readTimeout){
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
        return httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
    }
}
```

**App Code**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Autowired
    private GameSessionClient gameSessionClient;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        int playerNr = gameSessionClient.registerPlayer("test", true);
        logger.info("Response: {}", playerNr);
    }
}
```

The `return restOperations.getForObject(url, int.class);` results in a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

url: `http://localhost:8080/registerPlayer/test/1` or `http://localhost:8080/registerPlayer?name=test&mode=1` both result in `1` when using my browser

Any help would be much appreciated, as I'm getting pretty confused from this.

Comment: Please do keep in mind that this is a very common error message that has lots of information on how to solve already.

Comment: Please also see: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: restOperations is not being injected properly. Check again.

Comment: Can you rename `createRestTemplate` to `restOperations`.

Comment: Renaming it to `restOperations` did not work.
Although I changed: `private RestOperations restOperations;` to `private RestOperations restOperations = new RestConfig().createRestTemplate(new RestConfig().clientHttpRequestFactory(10000,10000));
`
Which is a work around, still trying to figure out why it's not AutoWiring

Answer (score 0):

Update you code to below..will remove the NullPointer Exception your getting:

```
@Bean
    public RestOperations restOperations(final ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory){
        return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
    }
```

and do this , instead of "Application.class":

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}
```

Comment: As explained above, renaming it is still giving me a `NullPointerException`

Comment: updated my answer..you have Application.class, and not App.class(to match the name of the class)